# what is this encoding , and how to decode it?

Tags: asp.net, captcha

I saw this encoding in an ASP captcha image, I want to know what type it is, and how to decode it (if possible!)

Examples:

`AJKF        ==>     Qp6TyMd9r7hGWwymcayiwg==`

`CQQL        ==>     b0oFR8d/QBNbGT2Ov8gx3g==`

I didn't have the script code.

The encoding is from captcha image url in a polling, so I have to refresh the polling page to get a new url the contains decoded string.

http://www.aljazeera.net/Portal/KServices/Controles/SecureCAPTCHA/GenerateImage.aspx?Code=b0oFR8d/QBNbGT2Ov8gx3g==&Length=4

http://www.aljazeera.net/Portal/KServices/Controles/SecureCAPTCHA/GenerateImage.aspx?Code=Qp6TyMd9r7hGWwymcayiwg==&Length=4

Comment: and reading that script didn't tell you what encoding it was?

Comment: Can you only encode 4 letter strings or any strings? For example, if it is using salted MD5, encoding an empty string *could* give you the salt.

Comment: @schnaader: yeah, the md5 of the salt, so the salt itself, if the salt is poorly chosen. (+1)

Comment: I don't have the code or even the tool to perform such encoding.

Comment: So you're stuck, unless someone has an enlightening intuition. However, it's probably salted MD5 :)

Comment: EDIT (after your edit): so you want to break the captcha and create some robot to spam... OK, but it will be hard since they're probably encrypting the Code= arg in some way. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

The two strings are [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) representations of a 128 bit value, so it might be some sort of 128-bit hash of the input, but it doesn't seem to be as simple as [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) of the input string.

If it is a hash, it won't be possible to decode it because of collisions, although you could f.e. calculate hashes of `AAAA`...`ZZZZ` and build a lookup table, and for such short strings the chance of a collision is quite small.

The Base64 decoded hex values are (using [this converter](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/base64.php?lang=en)):

```
AJKF ==> Qp6TyMd9r7hGWwymcayiwg== ==> 429E93C8C77DAFB8465B0CA671ACA2C2

CQQL ==> b0oFR8d/QBNbGT2Ov8gx3g== ==> 6F4A0547C77F40135B193D8EBFC831DE
```

Google doesn't find matches for these both hex strings, so I guess it's either a custom hash or the input gets modified (f.e. salted).

Comment: +1 If you don't have the function, and the input is reasonably numerous, 'table' it.

Comment: maybe string + salting = md5 hash

Comment: I don't think that it's an MD5 hash , due to the representation of the decoding ..

Answer (score 1):

The ending step of the encoding process is `base64`, I have almost no doubt about that, but it has to include some previous step I can't clearly focus. Maybe some hashing function on the string bytes, and then `base64`? The worst case could be some actual *encryption* and then `base64` encoding.

Who can tell... Can you give us more example? And also, isn't there any other way to solve your problem?

**EDIT**: I'm convinced this is an MD5 hash of the string plus some unknown [salting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29). It's quite difficult to crack it.

Comment: That was clear. So give us more examples, ie what happens if the input string is longer?

Comment: I don't think that it's an MD5 hash , due to the representation of the decoding .

Comment: But what maps a string to a 128 bit sequence? However, if you don't provide more examples, here we are - stuck.